# beginner with hybrid app

Tags: ios, windows-phone-8, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a hybrid app using Cordova. I successfully tested and installed it on android. However I can not install it on iOS nor on Windows Phone. I am using Intel XDK to compile the application codes to a package. At the moment I want to verify that these hybrid apps work good enough before buying developer license for iOS and Windows Phone.

Is there any way to get the developer certificate(for iOS and anything else necessary) to successfully compile the app and create an app package?
Is it possible to install the app (packaged in the above question) without a Mac computer on iPhone?

How can I install the app on windows phone from windows 7 OS, if it is possible?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Intel XDK, you can install App Preview on an iPhone, Android or Windows Phone device.  This will let you test your app without an account.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/intel-app-preview/id725023841?mt=8

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intel.html5tools.apppreview&hl=en

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/intel-app-preview/5632e397-0a7c-4d34-b857-c2b7b8b046fa

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I already have that app preview, but some functions needs to be tested on real device as real app. For example insomnia does not work app preview (tested on android and ios) but when I compiled an android app and installed then it worked(insomnia) on the android device. I need to test these and some other things also on iOS and Windows Phone.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what "insomnia" is.  Your HTML/JS/CSS code will work in App Preview and a built app, unless you are using Cordova Plugins

Comment: Insomnia is a plugin for Hybrdid apps by Cordova people. It allows to keep the phone awake(i.e. screen remains on)

Comment: Ok.  If you use the Intel XDK cloud builds, you can do an over-the-air install of your application to test.  You *DO* need an iOS developer account.  But you still need a Mac to upload it to the store.